# ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION never occurs - Why?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In my attempts to understand the In-app Billing flow, I ran the [market_billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) sample, as is, plus a few Log.v() in key points, like in `BillingService.handleCommand()`:

```
public void handleCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Consts.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(TAG, "handleCommand() action: " + action);
    }
    if (Consts.ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
        String[] notifyIds = intent.getStringArrayExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
        confirmNotifications(startId, notifyIds);
    } else if (Consts.ACTION_GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION.equals(action)) {
        String notifyId = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
        getPurchaseInformation(startId, new String[] { notifyId });
    } else if (Consts.ACTION_PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        String signedData = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNED_DATA);
        String signature = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNATURE);
        purchaseStateChanged(startId, signedData, signature);
    } else if (Consts.ACTION_RESPONSE_CODE.equals(action)) {
        long requestId = intent.getLongExtra(Consts.INAPP_REQUEST_ID, -1);
        int responseCodeIndex = intent.getIntExtra(Consts.INAPP_RESPONSE_CODE,
                ResponseCode.RESULT_ERROR.ordinal());
        ResponseCode responseCode = ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);
        checkResponseCode(requestId, responseCode);
    }
}
```

My problem (?) is that I can see in the logs all actions being performed, but `ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION` never shows up for some reason, despite the transaction being successful.

Any idea why this is?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION is never used in BillingReceiver and I have no idea why they declare it in handleCommand as CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION should not be done here in the first place

Comment: Can you explain more about why `ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION` should not be done here in the first place? +1 for now.

Comment: to my understanding, ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION is used to confirm a notificationId so that google does not send us any more IN_APP_NOTIFY message. You are supposed to send this confirmation after you have confirmed your purchase. However, you can see that the sample code confirm notification in purchaseStateChanged callback in the billingservice. Why they put ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION in handlecommand is beyond me because this is a application specific action instead of being received via the billingreceiver.

Answer (score 1):

The BillingReceiver is waiting for the IN_APP_NOTIFY message sent from the market. Then it would start the confirmation through the service. Does your receiver receive the IN_APP_NOTIFY message?

I have a similar issue too. My application does never get back the notification from the Market application. So there's actually nothing to confirm for your app.
It seems like it is a known issue for a long time already as you can see here: http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=14

Comment: Yes, of course I receive IN_APP_NOTIFY, otherwise the purchase wouldn't have been completed successfully (as mentioned in the original post). I am basically receiving everything as documented **except** for the `ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION`. This is weird. Could this be due to the fact that I have been only using `android.test.*` items, not real ones? (real ones require real payment, so I've been deferring this to a later stage). +1 for now.

Comment: The Market has to receive the CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION. You have to send it through your Service. In the sample application it happens in the BillingReceiver through notify(context,id). Try to get some logs in this method. 
There should not be any differences between the test item and your real items.